# Array of tuples in Swift

Tags: nsarray, tuples, swift, ios8

I have a function:

```
func parseJSON3(inputData: NSData) -> NSArray {
    var tempDict: (id:Int, ccomments:Int, post_date:String, post_title:String, url:String) = (id: 0, ccomments: 0, post_date: "null", post_title: "null", url: "null")
    var resultArray: (id:Int, ccomments:Int, post_date:String, post_title:String, url:String)[] = []
    var error: NSError?
    var jsonDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(inputData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary
    var firstArray = jsonDictionary.objectForKey("locations") as NSArray
    for dict in firstArray {
        tempDict.id = dict.valueForKey("ID") as Int
        tempDict.ccomments = dict.valueForKey("ccomments") as Int
        tempDict.post_date = dict.valueForKey("post_date") as String
        tempDict.post_title = dict.valueForKey("post_title") as String
        tempDict.url = dict.valueForKey("url") as String
        resultArray.append(tempDict)
    }
    return resultArray
}
```

In line

**resultArray.append(tempDict)**

I have an error:

**Missing argument for parameter 'ccomments' in call**

Why? Help please....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks to me like `resultArray.append()` is treating the tuple a little bit like a variadic parameter, and trying to expand the tuple to match its own arguments. It's complaining about your second parameter because it's only expecting one. I haven't seen this behavior for `Array.append()` documented anywhere, so I would say it's a bug in Swift.

Using the appending operator `+=` doesn't seem to have that issue:

```
resultArray += tempDict
```

Comment: I don't believe this describes the behavior, see my answer for some interesting results of my investigation!

Answer (score 9):

So this is pretty wild - not sure if I would qualify it as a bug or as undocumented behavior, but it's definitely something that should be on the radar for a fix / clarification!

The situation is that `append` is treating your argument `tempDict` (which we would expect to be the only argument to an Array method that takes a single member and adds it to the collection) as the *first* argument in a signature where it is looking for 5 arguments (!), one for each member of the Tuple type that the Array holds.

See the following for some interesting behavior (including assigning a label to the single member of a 1-member 'Tuple' ??) ->

```
var arrayOne: Array<String> = []
arrayOne.append("hi")
println(arrayOne[0])        // hi

var arrayTwo: Array<(String)> = []    // where (String) is a single-member Tuple
arrayTwo.append("hi")
println(arrayTwo[0])        // hi
println(arrayTwo[0].0)      // hi  -> using .0 subscript to access the first member of the Tuple

// wanna see something crazy? remember arrayOne, that holds members of type String?
println(arrayOne[0].0)      // hi  -> this Array does not hold Tuples, but it looks like we can still treat its members like "single-member Tuples"?

var arrayThree: Array<(str: String)> = []    // members of the Array are single-member Tuples with the label 'str' for their member
arrayThree.append(str: "hi")                 // now we can't use append without providing the label 'str', acting as what looks like an argument label?
var byeString = "bye"
var byeTuple = ("bye")
arrayThree += byeString     // += doesn't care about the label, and will take either a String or a single-member Tuple holding a String
arrayThree += byeTuple
println(arrayThree[0])      // hi
println(arrayThree[0].0)    // hi
println(arrayThree[0].str)  // hi  -> accessing the single member of the Tuple by its label
```

...so in your case, where you are seeing the error with `append` what it wants you to do is (using the labels you used to declare the Tuple as something that looks like argument labels):

```
var resultArray: (id:Int, ccomments:Int, post_date:String, post_title:String, url:String)[] = []
...
resultArray.append(id: someIntValue, ccomments: someOtherIntValue, post_date: someStringValue, post_title: someOtherStringValue, url: someAnotherStringValue)
```

...and of course, as discussed, you can avoid doing that by just using `+=` instead

Crazy stuff! could be by design to serve some purpose, could be a consequence of protocol inheritance that wasn't meant to have this effect... would be interesting to know the answer!

Comment: This is really interesting (and still happening in Beta 3). I guess it has something to do with the fact that `func foo(x:Int,y:String)` has the same effect as `func foo((x:Int,y:String))`.

Answer (score 0):

`resultArray.append()` seems to be taking `tempDict` as the first tuple element (`id`).

Changing it to :

`resultArray += tempDict`

seems to compile and work.

I'm not sure why `append()` doesn't behave the same way, maybe you can file a bug!