# How do I create an array of tuples?

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

I'm trying to create an array of tuples in Swift, but having great difficulty:

```
var fun: (num1: Int, num2: Int)[] = (num1: Int, num2: Int)[]()
```

The above causes a compiler error.

Why's that wrong? The following works correctly:

```
var foo: Int[] = Int[]()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array of tuples in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210692/array-of-tuples-in-swift)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It works with a type alias:

```
typealias mytuple = (num1: Int, num2: Int)

var fun: mytuple[] = mytuple[]()
// Or just: var fun = mytuple[]()
fun.append((1,2))
fun.append((3,4))

println(fun)
// [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

*Update:* As of Xcode 6 Beta 3, the array syntax has changed:

```
var fun: [mytuple] = [mytuple]()
// Or just: var fun = [mytuple]()
```

Comment: This has changed for Swift - Beta 3.

Comment: @vacawama: You are right (but the old syntax still works, just causing a compiler warning). I have updated the answer accordingly. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this, just your assignment is overly complicated:

```
var tupleArray: [(num1: Int, num2: Int)] = [ (21, 23) ]
```

or to make an empty one:

```
var tupleArray: [(num1: Int, num2: Int)] = []
tupleArray += (1, 2)
println(tupleArray[0].num1)    // prints 1
```

Comment: You are right! `var tupleArray: (num1: Int, num2: Int)[] = []` just works.

Comment: Yeah, tuples and arrays are seriously quirky. This Q&A has more strangeness: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210692/array-of-tuples-in-swift

Comment: This has changed for Swift - Beta 3.

Comment: @vacawama Yeah, not sure I want to go through all my answers and update the syntax, but I feel bad having invalid code out there...

Answer (score 3):

This also works:

```
var fun:Array<(Int,Int)> = []
fun += (1,2)
fun += (3,4)
```

Oddly though, `append` wants just one set of parens:

```
fun.append(5,6)
```

If you want the labels for the `tuple` parts:

```
var fun:Array<(num1: Int, num2: Int)> = []
fun += (1,2)                  // This still works
fun.append(3,4)               // This does not work
fun.append(num1: 3, num2: 4)  // but this does work
```

Comment: This is a bug/feature in Swift with arrays of tuples. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210692/array-of-tuples-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about earlier versions of Swift, but this works in Swift 3 when you want to provide initial values:

```
var values: [(num1: Int, num2: Int)] = {
    var values = [(num1: Int, num2: Int)]()
    for i in 0..<10 {
        values.append((num1: 0, num2: 0))
    }
    return values
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Swift 5.7, the following works.

1. Creating an empty array that you can populate later, using the standard array initialiser with the tuple's type signature.

```
/* Create empty array of (num1: Int, num2: Int) tuples */
var array1 = [(num1: Int, num2: Int)]()

/* Can be populated with (Int, Int) tuples
   (the labels are optional)... */
for i in 1...8 {
  array1.append((i, i*i))
}

/* ...or (num1: Int, num1: Int) tuples */
for i in 9...12 {
  array1.append((num1: i, num2: i*i))
}
```

2. Creating an initialised array using `Array(repeating: <value>, count:)`:

```swift
var array2 = Array(repeating: (num1: 0, num2: 0), count: 8)
```

Answer (score -2):

It can be done like this as well.

```
      var arr : [(num1: Int, num2 : Int)] = {
          let arr =  Array(repeating: (num1:  0, num2 :0), count : n)
          return arr
     }()
```