# How do I create an array of tuples in Swift where one of the items in the tuple is optional?

Tags: swift, tuples

Take the following code:

```
var tupleArray: [(firstName: String, middleName: String?)] = []
tupleArray.append(firstName: "Bob", middleName: nil)
tupleArray.append(firstName: "Tom", middleName: "Smith") // causes an error
```

I want an array of tuples consisting of a first name and a middle name, the middle name can be nil or have a value (thus, optional). However with the above creation code the third line gives me an error. Why? How do I get around this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This could be a compiler bug. As in [How do I create an array of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539679/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-tuples),
you can define a type alias as a workaround:

```
typealias NameTuple = (firstName: String, middleName: String?)

var tupleArray: [NameTuple] = []
tupleArray.append( (firstName: "Bob", middleName: nil) )
tupleArray.append( (firstName: "Tom", middleName: "Smith") )
```

Comment: I would probably go further and say if you are going to use tuples with named values, you might as well go for a full on struct, which does away with needing the typealias. `middleName` could even be defaulted to `nil` which allows for neater initialisers.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround would be making `Optional<String>.Some` explicitly.

```
var tupleArray: [(firstName: String, middleName: String?)] = []
tupleArray.append(firstName: "Bob", middleName: nil)
tupleArray.append(firstName: "Tom", middleName: .Some("Smith"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Something Intresting.It seems to be as some bug but we can add using some other syntax try using following way

```
var pfc : [(prime: Int, count: Int)] = []

pfc.append(prime: 2, count: 2)

pfc += [(prime: 3, count: 4)]

var p = 5
var c = 1

var tuple = (prime: p, count: c)

pfc += [tuple]
```

for optinal variables go through the following code ([originally provided by Martin R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925348/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-tuples-in-swift-where-one-of-the-items-in-the-tuple/26925728#26925728)) it works fine for me

```
    typealias tupleArray =  (firstName: String, middleName: String?)

    var fun1: [tupleArray] = [tupleArray]()
    fun1.append((firstName: "Bob", middleName: nil))
    fun1.append((firstName: "Tom", middleName: "Smith"))
    println(fun1)
```

Comment: Nice of you to edit your answer to include the solution from someone else.

Comment: You can't just copy the answer of someone else without attribution. I've edited the above to include that.