# Strange Bool type from UI control

Tags: ios, swift, types, uikit

I have an array of `(String,Bool)` tuples:

```
var names : [(name:String, important:Bool)] = [("Paul",true), ("Peter",false)]
```

I also have a `UISwitch` control:

```
@IBOutlet weak var importantSwitch: UISwitch!
```

I want to add to the array, using the switch state to determine the `Bool`.

The following does *not* work:

```
names.append( name: "whatever", important: importantSwitch.on )
```

The issue reported by XCode is "type T does not conform to protocol IntegerLiteralConvertible".

These do work:

```
let i : Bool = importantSwitch.on
names.append( name: "whatever", important: i )
```

or

```
names.append( name: "whatever", important: importantSwitch.on==true )
```

My question, essentially, is, Why?

Comment: Arrays with tuples are still strange in Swift, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539679/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-tuples for a similar example. Defining a type alias can help here as well. (That doesn't answer the "why" though.)

Comment: @MartinR Okay, I think I've captured the "why".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and satisfying rewrite is to cast:

```
names.append(name: "whatever", important: importantSwitch.on as Bool)
```

Even better, if you don't want to perform *any* casting or assignment dance, then use `extend` instead of `append`:

```
names.extend([(name: "whatever", important: importantSwitch.on)])
```

As Martin R has said, a type alias also solves it, because it lets you provide a constructor expicitly:

```
typealias Pair = (name:String, important:Bool)
var names = [Pair]()
names.append(Pair(name: "whatever", important: importantSwitch.on))
```

I think the fact that `extend` works directly and `append` does not shows what the problem is: it's the tuple syntax. The trouble here is that - although this is a little-known fact - a function parameter list, and thus the argument list in a function call, is *itself* actually a tuple.

Thus when you say `names.append(...)`, is the thing in parentheses the argument list - are you trying to call `append` as if *it* had named parameters `name:` and `important:` - or is it *itself* a tuple that you want to append? Swift knows that this is an array of tuples and tries to work it out, but it needs a bit of help. You might think we could resolve this with an extra set of parentheses, but no such luck; I think this is because multiple nested parens are meaningless (they are cast away to a single set of parens early in the parsing process). With `extend`, however, we can write the literal array with the literal tuple inside it, and there is no ambiguity. The typealias and constructor is similarly unambiguous.

Comment: But that doesn't actually answer his question. `UISwitch` documentation reports `on` to be a `Bool`. Why would you have to cast it again as what it already is?

Comment: The same problem happens if you replace UISwitch with a custom pure Swift class having a `var on: Bool` property. So this is ***not*** a BOOL->Bool bridging or Objective-C->Swift bridging problem.

Comment: I agree that the error indicates that it's not a `Bool`, but there's no way to know that from the documentation, which would appear to indicate that this behavior is a bug. If Apple says it's a `Bool` but it's actually something else behind the scenes that won't act as a `Bool`, that's bad programming.

Comment: @mbm29414 Okay, I think I've come up with a proper explanation and have revised accordingly. Thanks for pushing me. :)

Comment: @matt Now it's a fantastic answer! ;-) Still, though, it seems like a bug since it violates the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: @mbm29414 I find a lot of Swift astonishing. Contravariant function parameter types still stun me. http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/type-variance-in-swift

Comment: If it is a matter of tuple vs parameter list ambiguity, why do extra parentheses ( `names.add((name: "whatever", important: importantSwitch.on))` ) not help with `add`? That was actually the very first thing I tried.

Comment: @DCS I've had the same problem in other contexts in Swift. I think multiple parentheses are cast away (ignored) at an earlier phase by the parser. Double parens never mean something different from single parens.

Comment: @DCS by the way this is a good use case for a bug report to Apple.

Comment: @matt Understood. Maybe you could add this to your answer, for future readers. I'll see whether I can bug-report at Apple without being a registered dev.

Comment: @DCS No worries, I'll submit it if you like. Very nice example. We've clearly hit an edge case in the parser. - Do note also Martin R's suggested workaround of using a type alias. I've added that to my answer. It's just the tuple members as direct params that causes the problem.