# Appending tuples to an array of tuples

Tags: swift, option-type

My class declares an array

```
var laps: (start: NSDate!, end: NSDate!)[] = []
```

When a tuple is added to this array I'd like to be able to do something like

```
let now = NSDate()
var lap = (now, nil)
laps.append(lap)
```

But at the `append` I get the error `Missing argument for parameter 'end' in call`.

Comment: see my answer with investigation and conclusions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210692/array-of-tuples-in-swift - I hope it helps!

Comment: This isn't an answer, obviously, but don't do this. Tuples are designed for temporary use and will miss out on a lot of Swift's strengths (compiler optimizations, etc.). It would be better to create a simple nested struct inside your class to hold these two values and make an array of those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tried to following, and it looked correct syntactically:

```
typealias MyTuple = (start: NSDate!, end: NSDate?)
```

then in the method, I did:

```
var laps: Array<MyTuple> = Array()
laps.append((NSDate.date(), nil))
```

Comment: The key to point out in this answer is that end date is optional (NSDate?) which allows you to pass in nil. If you use NSDate! and pass in a nil then you'll get the error about the params not matching.

Answer (score 5):

There's a bug in using `.append` with arrays of tuples. You can use the `+=` operator instead:

```
laps += lap
```

Comment: It should be `laps += [lap]`. Surprisingly I didn't encounter this bug in `append` in Swift 1.2, but with Swift 2.0 Beta 2, I ran into this issue.