# Problems mixing Arrays, Tuples and Closures in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, closures, tuples

I am trying to manage an array of (`String`, closure) tuples.

The array is defined as:

```
var menuItems: [(title: String, closure: () -> Void)] = []
```

Now I'm trying to add items to it:

```
// 1. Adding directly a tuple fails with "Missing argument for parameter 'closure' in call"
menuItems.append((title: "any", closure: {}))
```

```
// 2. Using let works
let item: (title: String, closure: () -> Void) = (title: "any", closure: {})
menuItems.append(item)
```

```
// 3. Using var fails with "Missing argument for parameter 'closure' in call"
var item: (title: String, closure: () -> Void) = (title: "any", closure: {})
menuItems.append(item)
```

Any explanation or better way to add items would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't tell you exactly why adding a var item isn't possible however I _can_ tell you that adding such a closure directly isn't possible as the compiler can't infer the type `() -> Void`, I suppose.

Comment: The problem is unrelated to closures, but array of tuples *are strange*. Similar questions with answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539679/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-tuples, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575331/appending-tuples-to-an-array-of-tuples, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076227/how-to-append-a-tuple-to-an-array-object-in-swift-code, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418724/appending-to-an-empty-array-giving-error – pick your "duplicate" :)

Comment: ... or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210692/array-of-tuples-in-swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 and 3's ambiguity seems to be due to Swift compiler bugs, as is using `menuItems[0].closure` directly which causes compiler segmentation faults.

1 works fine once I remove the parentheses for the tuple, which also seems non-logical.

```
menuItems.append(title: "any", closure: {})
```

Anyway I expect this to change/break in future Swift/compiler updates.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's an ambiguity concerning the type of the tuple. If you define a `typealias` the problem goes away:

```
typealias MenuItem = (title: String, closure: () -> Void)
var menuItems: [MenuItem] = []
var item: MenuItem = (title: "any", closure: {})
let item2: MenuItem = (title: "another", closure: {})
menuItems.append(item)
menuItems.append(item2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have virtually the same solution as Kenneth. He beat me to it. The only extra thing I'd add is that getting the items out again you can't write `menuItems[0].closure` you must declare a constant or variable for `menuItems[0]` first, otherwise the Playground goes haywire (and I suspect therefore it would cause problems in an app too). I'm guessing that it is something to do with the complexity.

```
typealias tuple = (title: String, closure: () -> Void)

var menuItems = [tuple]()

menuItems.append((title: "any", closure: {}))
let anItem = menuItems[0]
anItem.closure
anItem.title
```

Comment: Once again, it seems to be an issue with ambiguity. If you do `(menuItems[0] as MenuItem).title` it works without a crash.

Comment: Yes, using `menuItems[0].closure` directly causes a segmentation fault in the compiler!