# missing argument for parameter in call in tuple

Tags: swift, tuples

So I am working on a menu-type class and for some reason I am getting the error: "Missing argument for parameter 'dishes' in call"

Here is the code:

```
class Meal {
    var nameOfMeal: String
    var menu : [(sectionName: String, dishes: [Dish])]
    var hours: String

    init(nameOfMeal: String, menuIDs: [(sectionName: String, dishIDs: [String])], hours: String) {
        self.nameOfMeal = nameOfMeal
        setMenuFromIDs(menuIDs)
        self.hours = hours
    }

    func setMenuFromIDs(menuIDs: [(sectionName: String, dishIDs: [String])]){
        menu = []
        for menuSection in menuIDs {
            var loadedDishes = CoreDataUtility.loadArrayOfDishesFromIDs(menuSection.dishIDs)
            menu.append((sectionName: menuSection.sectionName, dishes: loadedDishes))
        }
    }

}
```

The error is on the `menu.append((sectionName: menuSection.sectionName....))`

I have checked the type of `menu`, `loadedDishes`, I've separated the argument in `menu.append` and checked it's type and they're all appearing as they should. None are optionals. I've removed the `sectionName` and `dishes` label from the tuple but the error still mysteriously appears.

Can anyone please help me figure out why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nate Cook [said here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575331/appending-tuples-to-an-array-of-tuples):

> … don't do this. Tuples are designed for temporary use and will miss out on a lot of Swift's strengths (compiler optimizations, etc.) …

Based on that answer, I rewrote your code as:

```
typealias MyTuple = (sectionName: String, dishes:[Dish])

class Meal {
    var nameOfMeal: String
    var menu : [MyTuple]
    var hours: String

    init(nameOfMeal: String, menuIDs: [(sectionName: String, dishIDs: [String])], hours: String) {
        self.nameOfMeal = nameOfMeal
        self.hours = hours
        self.menu = [("", [Dish]())]
        setMenuFromIDs(menuIDs)
    }

    func setMenuFromIDs(menuIDs: [(sectionName: String, dishIDs: [String])]){
        menu = []
        for menuSection in menuIDs {
            var loadedDishes = CoreDataUtility.loadArrayOfDishesFromIDs(menuSection.dishIDs)
            menu.append((menuSection.sectionName, loadedDishes))
        }
    }

}
```

… and it now compiles!

*Note that I also moved the line `setMenuFromIDs(menuIDs)` to the bottom of the `init` function and initialised your `menu` property (to avoid another compiler warning, of using self before its initialized).*

Comment: Quite good timing. I was messing around with the code trying to figure out what was wrong and I decided to typealias the tuple to make it simpler. made all the fixes that you made and it does indeed compile :D Thanks!

Comment: It's like the universe connected us for a second ^_^