# How can i add a tuples value to Swift array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have the array:

```
var myArray:[(Int,Int)] = []
```

But when I add value to it by:

```
myArray.append((1,2))
```

The compiler show mistake warning. What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array of tuples in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210692/array-of-tuples-in-swift) - In short: `myArray.append(1,2)` works (don't know if this is intended or a Swift bug). `myArray += (1,2)` works as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    var myArray:(Int,Int)[] = []
    myArray.append( 1,1 );
    print("myArray =\(myArray)");
```

The above code works fine

Comment: Note that the above example uses pre-beta 3 syntax for array types. The correct syntax now is to place parentheses around the value type, not after them.

Answer (score 4):

Your tuple doesn't need a second set of parentheses around it. This works fine:

```
myArray.append( 1,1 );
```